# Set Bluno Beetle to Broadcast mode

Tags: bluetooth

I recently purchased Bluno Beetle (basically a smaller Arduino with a BLE chip). It is based on the Bluno: [Wiki](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Bluno_SKU:DFR0267#Wireless_Programming_via_BLE) I know that its Bluetooth Chip, the TI CC2540, supports the Broadcast mode: [Official page](http://www.ti.com/product/CC2540/description)

However I can't find any [AT commands](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Bluno_SKU:DFR0267#AT_Command_List) that would allow me to set it to this mode, does anyone of you have an idea? I am trying to relay the messages they are sending (sensor readings), essentially building an interconnected network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Bluno only supports the Central and Peripheral roles (i.e. not the Broadcaster and Observer roles.) Keep in mind AT commands are a feature of the firmware, not the actual chip. As such, even if the chip supports a particular mode or role, that doesn't necessarily mean the firmware makes the feature available.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :-/ Thanks for your answer though!